# PHPBrew Installation failed with Git LANG error

Tags: php, phpbrew

I am trying to installe a PHPBrew enviroment, have tried different versions, I am running this command:

```
phpbrew install 5.4.42 +default
```

Have tried:

```
phpbrew install 5.4.44 +default
```

and:

```
phpbrew install 5.4.44
```

WIth the same error
I have installed all the requirements present in here
https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/wiki/Requirement

Error:

```
git: 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

make: *** [ext/date/php_date.lo] Error 1
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and this is the output of running LOCALE

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 git
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) and see if some of the git environment variables is set to 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8'.